# How to make Web ISO work in Virtual Media on SuperMicro ipmi?

Tags: mount, ipmi, supermicro, iso, media

How does Virtual Media Web ISO work on SuperMicro ipmi?
I am using SuperMicro sever. I want to be able to mount bootable ISO image to a server, launch long process there (disk formatting), and then turn off my laptop. But if I do it, the remote booted OS will hang, because of virtual CD ROM will become unreadable.

In ipmi java application in Virtual Storage there is an item called Web ISO.
I thought I could upload my ISO to a personal site, and make it available over http(s), so media will stay online even when I turn off my laptop.
But the "Image File Name and Full Path" field and "Open Image" button for the web iso are greyed out, so I cannot select it.
I also checked that java application in Windows OS, and still that button is greyed out there.
[image: Image File Name and Full Path]
Is it possible to mount an iso image from a web site as a virtual storage?

Answer (score 2):

From the supermicro ipmi manual:

> Web ISO: Select this feature to select a Web ISO and mount it from the
>   web page. The file will be mounted from the web interface. To specify
>   the file location, set the image path on the CD-ROM Image page in the
>   IPMI.

So under web iso they mean not your personal site, but a web page of ipmi. That page allows you to set a samba share.

You can store a samba share on an IP that is accessible from network in which ipmi works, possibly in the public internet. You can see how to configure a share here https://ahelpme.com/linux/tips/configure-and-mount-samba-share-in-supermicro-ipmi-virtual-media-cd-rom/

---

This could be an answer to my own question, but even when configured some values in the CD ROM page of ipmi web interface, the option is still unusable (greyed out). Help and improving an answer is appreciated.

---

Also, I have found out that supermicro-update-manager can mount using http. From manual:

```
MountIsoImage
--image_url <URL>
The URLs to access the shared ISO image
SAMBA URL: 'smb://<host name or ip>/<shared point>/<file path>'
SAMBA UNC: '\\<host name or ip>\<shared point>\<file path>'
HTTP URL: 'http://<host name or ip>/<shared point>/<file path>'
```

So I tried

```
supermicro-update-manager --no_banner -i ipmi.yourserver.ru -u ADMIN -f ~/.ipmi-password.txt -c MountIsoImage --image_url http://your-domain.ru/archlinux.iso
```

But I got

```
********************************<<<<<ERROR>>>>>*********************************

ExitCode                = 38
Description             = Function is not supported
Program Error Code      = 282.41
Error message:
        Mount ISO image via Http protocol is not supported by this BMC FW.

********************************************************************************
```

And this is probably the key of the problem. Seems like BMC FW should support this function. I need to update BMC and check and also check on different motherboards.

Answer (score 0):

To by able to mount the ISO by SuperMicro IPMI the ISO has to by reachable by the IPMI interface e.g. the Webserver providing the file has to by in same network as IPMI (not one of the default NICx networks).

You can mount the ISO image by, then reboot the server manually:

```
sum -i ${BMC_HOST} -u ${BMC_USER} -p ${BMC_PASS} -c MountIsoImage --image_url http://${ISO_SERVER_IP}/iso/${ISO}
```

Also (at least currently) to by able to boot UEFI ISO image you have to manually choose Boot Device by pressing F11 on boot time and select "UEFI: ATEN Virtual CDROM XXX".